# Printing the array using print and serial write function in Arduino Uno

Tags: serial, softwareserial, array, print

I have, one program with only using printing array and other with serial write and print function for the array, while using serial write and print function I get these extra characters between the data as shown below, can anyone help me with this

Printing the array with print function

```cpp
uint8_t a[13] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0X77, 0x88,
                 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
int i;

void Print_Hexa(uint8_t num) {
  char Hex_Array[2];

  sprintf(Hex_Array, "%02X", num);
  Serial.print(Hex_Array);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    //Serial.write(a[i]);
    Print_Hexa(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
}
```

[image: Using Print Function]

Using with serial write and print function for array

```cpp
uint8_t a[13] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0X77, 0x88,
                 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
int i;

void Print_Hexa(uint8_t num) {
  char Hex_Array[2];

  sprintf(Hex_Array, "%02X", num);
  Serial.print(Hex_Array);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    Serial.write(a[i]);
    Print_Hexa(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
}
```

[image: Using Serial write and Print function for array]

Comment: `Serial.write(a[i]);` sends a character but not all values are readable characters

Comment: To prevent buffer overruns, use `snprintf(Hex_Array, sizeof(Hex_Array), "%02X", num);`. More info [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Also be aware that the Arduino versions don't support the `%f` format specifier.

Answer (score 6):

`Serial.write(some_byte)` writes a byte on the serial output. The
Arduino serial monitor tries to interpret the bytes it receives as text:

- `0x11` is a control character, displayed as “□”
- `0x22` is the ASCII code for the double quote (")
- `0x33` is the ASCII code for the digit 3.
- `0x44` is the ASCII code for the uppercase letter “D”
- etc.

Comment: Is it possible to remove them or mask them if possible

Comment: @voticoy: Sure! Remove the `Serial.write()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

To store a 2 character string you need a 3 byte array, not a 2 byte array. This is because in C a string consists of the actual string data *and* a zero ("NULL") byte at the end to indicate where the end of the string is.

So you would need:

```
char Hex_Array[3];
```

so it can store, for the number 0x69: `69\0`. Otherwise you overrun the array and corrupt other data that follows in the stack, and changing that other data corrupts your string by changing the "end of string" marker to some other random ASCII character.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed the array size to 3 as mentioned, still in the serial monitor output remains the same.